# Equations for rotational transformations of a quadratic

Tags: geometry, quadratics, transformation

Just a question for fun:

I noted that the curves $y=x^2$ and $y=\sqrt{x}$ are in effect 'rotational transformations' of 90 degrees from each other when plotted on a graph, is there another equation which perhaps models, say a *45 degree* rotation of the equation $y=x^2$ or generally any rotation such that the line $y=mx$ acts as a line of symmetry for the equation?

here is  quick visualization of the problem: [image]

Any information on the topic would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rotate $y=a x^2+bx+c$ about the origin, you need to replace $x$ and $y$ by
$(x \cos (\theta )-y \sin (\theta ))$ and $(x \sin (\theta )+y \cos (\theta ))$, respectively. The replacements are just the coordinates of a 2D rotation matrix with angle $\theta$ times the vector $(x,y)$.

Comment: Great, so this means an equation for a rotation of 45 degrees would be $y=x\pm \!\,\sqrt{4\sqrt{2}x+2}+\sqrt{2}$

Comment: could you perhaps explain *why* that is the case though, because I'm not sure how you came up with those substitutions

Comment: I dont understand how you get an $x$ inside the square root. For a 45 degree rotation the substitutions makes $y = x^2$ into $(x+y)/\sqrt{2} = ((x-y)/\sqrt{2})^2$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Rotation

Answer (score 1):

A parabola is a locus. Specifically, the parabola $y=x^2$ is the set of points that are at the same distance from the point $(0,1/4)$ (the focus) and the line $y=-1/4$ (the directrix).

If you rotate the point and the line, you get the parabola you are asking for. The focus moves to 
$$\left(\frac1{4\sqrt 2},\frac1{4\sqrt 2}\right)$$
and the directrix becomes
$$x+y=-\frac1{2\sqrt 2}$$

There is much information about this topic in the [Wikipedia's article about parabola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#Cartesian)e.